# What is the probability that $x_1+x_2+...+x_n \le n$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

Given that $X_1, X_2...$ are mutually independent random variables. For each $i$ with $1\le i \le n$

- the variable $X_i$ is equal to either $0$ or $n+1$
- $E(X_i)$ = $1$

also.. if $X_i$ is equal to either $0$ or $n+1$, doesn't that mean that all $X_i$ need to be $0$?

Thanks

Comment: So $X_1, X_2,...X_n$ is a sequence of mutually independent random variables. Hopefully that clarifies. Sorry if I just re-expressed with the same words. No it is a homework problem I need help with. Thanks

Comment: "mutually independent random variable" isn't a thing. You probably "independent random variable", ie the value of $X_1$ doesn't affect the probability distribution for $X_2$

Comment: Stella: “Mutually independent random variables” is a pretty common phrase. What do you mean when you say it’s not a thing? Pairwise independence doesn’t imply mutual independence when there are more than 2 variables.

Comment: "doesn't that mean that all $X_i$ need to be 0?" Exactly. Can't you go on from there?

Comment: If you know each $X_i$ can only take the values $0,n+1$, and $E(X_i)=1$, you can compute $P(X_i=0)$ and $P(X_i=n+1)$. As you noted, the only way $\sum X_i\leq n$ is if all $X_i$ are zero; since you know $P(X_i=0)$ for each $i$, and since you know the $X_i$ are mutually independent, you can now compute $P(\sum X_i\leq n)=P(X_i=0\mbox{ for all }i)$.

Comment: I don't think so, for each i$ \leq x_i \geq n$, $P(X_{1}) = 0$ or $n+1$, Similarly, $P(X_{2}) = 0$ or $n+1$ and so on  had it been like $P(X_{1}) = 0$ or $i+1$, then what you say is right.  Else the notation is simple.  Am I being wrong?

Comment: @FelixMarin: I don't get it, the problem states that each $E(X_i) = 1$, how can $E(X_1) = 1$ if, say $P_1(0) = P_1(n+1) = 1/2$? I don't know, but can I solve it this way, I'll use the fact that $E(X_i) = 1$ to solve for the probability of $P(X_i = 0)$, whose values are the same for all $i$, then just multiply them together and get the result?

Comment: @user49685 $\large 1 = p\times 0 + q\times \left(n + 1\right)$. Then, $\large q = {1 \over n + 1}$ and $\large p=1 - q = {n \over n + 1}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin And by this exact computation the distribution of $X_i$ DOES NOT depend on $i$. Note that $n$ is fixed once and for all hence your computation of $P_1$ and $P_2$ some comments ago are wrong.

Comment: @Did I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Since $\ds{X_{j} = 0\ \mbox{or}\ \pars{n + 1}\,\ \forall j = 1,2,\ldots,n}$ the solution requires $\ds{X_{j} = 0\,,\ \forall j = 1,2,\ldots,n}$. Since the probability of any $\ds{X_{J} = 0}$ is $\ds{n \over n + 1}$, the probability of $\ds{X_{j} = 0,\ \forall j}$ is given by
$\ds{\underbrace{{n \over n + 1}\ldots{n \over n + 1}}_{\ds{n\ \mbox{times}}}
=\color{#00f}{\large\pars{n \over n + 1}^{n}}}$

> However, in order  to illustrate a general method we perform the following calculation which, of course, agrees with the above result:
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\large\sum_{\braces{X_{j}}}P_{1}\pars{X_{1}}\ldots P_{n}\pars{X_{n}}
> \Theta\pars{n - X_{1} - \cdots - X_{n}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{\braces{X_{j}}}P_{1}\pars{X_{1}}\ldots P_{n}\pars{X_{n}}
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> {\expo{\ic k\pars{n - X_{1} - \cdots - X_{n}}} \over k - \ic 0^{+}}
> \,{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic kn} \over k - \ic 0^{+}}
> \bracks{{n \over n + 1}\,\expo{-\ic k0}
>         + {1 \over n + 1}\,\expo{-\ic k\pars{n + 1}}}^{n}
> \,{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> {\expo{\ic kn} \over k - \ic 0^{+}}
> \bracks{n + \expo{-\ic k\pars{n + 1}} \over n + 1}^{n}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \pars{n + 1}^{n}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> {\expo{\ic kn} \over k - \ic 0^{+}}\sum_{j = 0}^{n}{n \choose j}n^{n - j}
> \expo{-\ic jk\pars{n + 1}}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \pars{n + 1}^{n}}\sum_{j = 0}^{n}{n \choose j}n^{n - j}\
> \overbrace{%
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic k\bracks{n - j\pars{n + 1}}} \over k - \ic 0^{+}}
> \,{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{=\ \delta_{j0}}}\
> =\color{#00f}{\large\pars{n \over n + 1}^{n}}
> \end{align}
>   [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

For example, for $Y_i$ = $X_1 +X_2$ , the number of possible dintinct values could be 0, n+1, 2(n+1).  And the frequency of them is {0,0},{0,n+1},{n+1,0},{n+1,n+1}= ${2\choose0}0, {2\choose1}(n+1), {2\choose2} (2(n+1)$.

If you extend this to $Y_i = X_1 + X_2 +\cdots+ X_n$

The discrete appearances of 0, n+1, 2(n+1),... n(n+1) will follow a binomial distribution  with probability p of $(X_i = 0) = \frac{n}{n+1}$ and probability of q $(X_i = n+1) = \frac{1}{n+1}$ making the $E(X_i) = 1$. and the thus the probability

$$P(Y_i \leq n) = P(Y_i = 0)= \frac{{n\choose n}p^n.q^0}{{n\choose0}p^0.q^n + {n\choose1}p^{1}p^{n-1}+\cdots + {n\choose n}p^{n}q^{0}}$$ as 0 is the only possible value less than n.  The denominator becomes equal to one.

$$P(Y_i \leq n) = ({\frac{n}{n+1}})^{n}$$

That will be the required probability

Remark:

If $X_1, X_2,X_3,\cdots X_n$ be independent bernoulli random variables with $P(X_i = 0) = p$, Then $Y = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$ is a binomial random variable.

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: There is a "purist" around. I got a down vote too.

Comment: I think your answer is very readable, however, I kinda lost your train of thought between "and the thus the probability ...." to where you present $P(Y_i \leq n) = (\frac{n}{n+1})^n$  Can you explain these steps why you choose to make the final answer the probability of $p^n$

Comment: $P(Y_i \leq n)$ is only possible when $\sum X_i = o$ of all possible values. In the binomial distribution, $\sum X_i = 0$ only when all $X_i 's$ are zeros.  Suppose if the question were to ask the $P(Y_i \leq 2n)$, Then the required probability would have been $$P(Y_i \leq n+1) = P(Y_i = 0) + P(Y_i = n+1) = {n\choose n} p^n q^0 + {n\choose n-1} p^{n-1}q^1 = ({\frac{n}{n+1}})^n + (n). \frac{(n)^{n-1}}{({n+1})^n}$$ assuming $n\gt 0$

Comment: If $P(Y_i\leq 3n)$, the the required probability would have been $$P(Y_i \leq 2(n+1)) = P(Y_i = 0) + P(Y_i = n+1)+P(Y_i = 2(n+1) = {n\choose n} p^n q^0 + {n\choose n-1} p^{n-1}q^1+{n\choose n-1} p^{n-2}q^2 = ({\frac{n}{n+1}})^n + (n). \frac{(n)^{n-1}}{({n+1})^n} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}. \frac{(n)^{n-2}}{({n+1})^n}$$